# Is there a way to create a summed-are table of a matrix with just one iteration?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, array-algorithms

Constrains:

You can't iterate the matrix more than once.

If we name the matrix A then there are two of those matrices available, one is 'read-only' and the other is 'read/write'. We will use the 'read/write' matrix to construct the summed-area table.

For example this code here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/submatrix-sum-queries/

Iterares 2 times: 1)  summing all columns
                  2)  summing all rows

Comment: Odd question, the normal algorithm already only makes one pass.

Comment: Can you describe 'that' normal algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Useful picture for summed area tables from Wikipedia:

[image: SAT]

During construction, we already have `A`, `B` and `C` (for the edges, they would be zero), and want to compute `D`. The area spanned by that rectangle is 1x1 in this case, so we know the sum of the rectangle is `X` where `X` is the number from the original matrix at the position of `D`, so `D = C + B - A + X`. `A` is subtracted because the areas belonging to `C` and `B` both contain the area of `A`.

Simply iterating over the matrix and filling every cell using that formula iterates over the matrix only once, and could even be done in-place (replacing the original matrix by its SAT) if your matrix was not read-only.

Comment: Why are we subtracting D - B - C from A if we need the sum of everything (aka D + B + C + A)  also what do you mean when you say SAT ?

Comment: @HashWizard the line with SUM is how the sum of the red rectangle would be computed if we already have the SAT (so D is the sum of the entire area above and to the left of D), but in this case that is actually the known quantity (the rectangle is 1x1 so the area is just one cell, and D does not exist yet since we're computing it). SAT is short for summer area table.